# Load shape ESRI to QGIS but not in correct position, how to reposition all of features on layer QGIS

Tags: shapefile, qgis, dxf

I have Autocad DXF which has a design plan. Dxf file that I converted to a shape file using ogr2ogr tools to be able to import the QGIS application with quite perfect.

In QGIS plugins are called "OpenLayers" to add a basemap layer like googlemap, openstreet and etc.. But after I saw, the position of the layer design plan that I created, not in accordance with the position I want on the basemap.

I have tried to using "drag and drop" or "move feature (s)" tools in QGIS, but very slowly and cause no response (HUNG).

Is there a way to quickly move a layer to match the desired position?

Comment: You will probably have better luck with this question on superuser.com

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I will try to post my question on superuser.com

Comment: There is a forum for GIS questions:
https://gis.stackexchange.com